# sqlite3 python, how to get bytes back from blob

Tags: python, sqlite, blob, libtorrent

I have put my torrent info, from torrent file in a bencoded format (by libtorrent) into a blob in a sqlite3 database like this:

```
conn = sqlite3.connect(self.path + '/files/torrents.db')
c = conn.cursor()
q = 'UPDATE torrents SET torrent = ? WHERE name = ?'
c.execute(q, (sqlite3.Binary(data),name))
conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

however if i retrieve the blob from the database with a select query, what i get back is a buffer object.. how do i turn that back into what i put into the database, or rather into the sqlite3.Binary 
i want my bencoded bytes object back.

Comment: Can you provide a complete example (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? When I try the obvious to extend this out into something that works, what I get back is a `bytes` object, not a buffer object. And besides, whichever one you get back has the same bytes you put into the `Binary`, so… what's the problem in the first place?

Comment: https://repl.it/repls/CelebratedAdolescentGlitch

Comment: Is it possible that you've done something weird, like registering adapters/converters, in code you haven't shown us?

Comment: @abarnert the libtorrent torrent_info class doesn't accept a buffer, so i got that error, however when i used the __str__ method of the buffer object the problem was resolved.

Comment: So the problem actually has nothing to do with how you're using sqlite, but how you're using libtorrent. If you want to answer it yourself, you should edit the question to contain code relevant to the actual problem rather than to a different part of your program that was working fine, and more generally to be about the right problem.

Answer (score 1):

i figured it out.. after calling the **str**() method of the buffer object i got what i needed.